line 1687 in build flutter
Target kernel_snapshot_program failed: Exception
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Script '/Users/builder/programs/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy' line: 1687

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.



Process 'command '/Users/builder/programs/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 56s
Running Gradle task 'bundleDebug'...                              177.7s
Gradle task bundleDebug failed with exit code 1
Build failed :|
Failed to build for Android

Clean and Rebuild the Project
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter build apk --debug
If still facing issue try to clean gradlew clean and re build
cd android
./gradlew clean
./gradlew build
cd ..

I am building the project on an external platform called a website, and everything it does is I do not use the commands codemagic
